# selecting the month day and year from a transaction table

Tags: mysql

i want to create two queries for my table which has fields name,surname and amount paid,the first query should select the day,month and the amount paid,the second query should select a month,year in that year and the total amount paid in that month,lets say john paid $200 on 2013-05-01,$400 on 2013-05-03,while peter paid $50 on 2013-04-08, i want the first query to output

```
month and day   amount
  05-01          200
  05-03          400
  04-08          50
```

and the second query should output

```
month and year   total
2013-05           600
2013-04            50
```

i know i can use the sum aggregate function to select the total but the tricky part is how to select the day and the month in the format above ,thanks in advance

Comment: This should be a straightforward question to answer, but can you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename\G` for the table you want help with? You don't mention a date field in your table, but its data type is important to the answer.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format if you're using a date datatype

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in MySQL to format the date for each query.

```
-- query 1
select date_format(date, '%m-%d') `m-d`,
  sum(amount) Total
from mytable
group by date_format(date, '%m-%d');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/653cd/6). Gives a result:

```
|   M-D | TOTAL |
-----------------
| 04-08 |    50 |
| 05-01 |   200 |
| 05-03 |   400 |

-- query 2
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') `Y-m`,
  sum(amount) Total
from mytable
group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/653cd/7). Gives the result:

```
|     Y-M | TOTAL |
-------------------
| 2013-04 |    50 |
| 2013-05 |   600 |
```